# Open source (or at least freeware) software for using any MIDI controller on Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, audio, midi

I have an Akai EWI USB (i.e. a MIDI controller to be played as a wind instrument).

Together with the controller, they sell a software named "Aria" and produced by Garritan. However, I have read a lot of people complaining about this software, which is however the only software that I know for playing my EWI USB.

With Aria, you can simply plug the controller on the USB of your laptop, and play. Aria includes a lot of possible instruments, from Trumpet, Saxophone or Violins, to electronic synths.

The problem is that Aria doesn't seem to work on Windows 10 (while it is working like a charm on Mac OS).
I have also tried Garage Band on Mac, and EWI works "quite well" with this software as well.

So now my question is: are there some (free and/or open source) software that I can use on Windows for playing my EWI USB?

Comment: a) To me this does not seem to be logical. Either the device is a real MIDI device and it will work with any MIDI program, not only Aria - or it isn't. b) the problem that it does not work on Windows 10 is a driver issue

Comment: Have you tried different Windows compatibility modes to get Aria to work?  Also, I can't be sure, but perhaps Jazz++ will work. I have used it for years and on different operating systems. But I haven't tested it on Windows 10.